# How to add CGI claws to raw footage

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Been messing around in blender a bit trying to find good ways to add CGI claws splitting through the knuckles of a hand. At first I thought I might just make a simple mesh the same shape as the hand and just make it a shadow catcher and have the cgi claws come through that. However, after I did this how would I show the skin splitting open? is there a way to make the front face a shadow catcher and the back face like mushy guts looking material?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so I think I've found a method. If I place a solidify modifier on the hand then I have an inward layer as well so the top layer is a shadow catcher and the inward can be the blood and stuff